# Java OpenCSV - Ignoring Fields with a Certain Value

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm parsing a dataset that uses `\N` as an indicator of a null field.

Is there a native-OpenCSV way of handling this?

Currently I am replacing this indicator with empty String before I pass it into the CSVReader using a [TranslatingReader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800021/3107019).

I have migrated to OpenCSV 4.3.2 and am using `CsvToBeanBuilder` as per new best practice.

An excerpt of my code is below although it's not quite an MCVE as I'm sure the answer is as simple as a method I'm missing. But I make one if required.

```
try (Reader reader = new TranslatingReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))))
{
    @Override
    public String translate(final String line)
    {
        return line.replace("\\N", "");
    }
})
{
    return new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(reader).withType(clazz).build().parse();
}
```